# Как заставить счетчик обновляться каждую секунду?

Tags: javascript, функции, счетчики

Функционал:

- По нажатию на кнопку "**Начать игру**" я получаю текущее время (сколько прошло с 01.01.1970 в милисекундах.
- По нажатию на кнопку "**Закончить**" я получаю текущее время и отнимаю время, которое получено было при нажатии на кнопку "Начать игру"
- По нажатию на кнопку **Сумма** я получаю сумму, на которую я наиграл

Вопрос:

- Как мне сделать, чтобы на кнопку **Сумма** мне не нужно было нажимать миллион раз, а чтобы она эта функция выполнялась каждую секунду сама, при условии, что "**Начать игру**" нажата?

```js
var tarifPerHour = 10;
var startPlayingTime;
var currentTime;


function resetStartTime() {
    startPlayingTime = new Date();
    return startPlayingTime.getTime();
}

function getCurrentTime(){
    currentTime = new Date();
    return currentTime.getTime();
}

function getTime(){
    var a = getCurrentTime() - startPlayingTime;
    return a;
}

function getMoney(){
    var price = getTime()/3600000*tarifPerHour;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = price.toFixed(2);
    return price;
}

function stopTime(){
    var price = getTime()/3600000*tarifPerHour;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = price.toFixed(2) + " рубля";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="resetStartTime()">Начать игру</button>
<button onclick="stopTime()">Закончить</button>
<button onclick="getMoney()">Сумма</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя материал из комментария @andreymal.

При нажатии на кнопку "Начать игру" включается таймер, выполняющий ту же функцию, что и при клике на кнопку "Сумма". При нажатии на "Закончить игру", таймер останавливается.

```js
var tarifPerHour = 10;
var startPlayingTime;
var currentTime;

var timerId = 0;  // числовой идентификатор таймера

function resetStartTime() {
    if (timerId) {
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }
    timerId = setInterval(getMoney, 1000); // запускаем таймер
    startPlayingTime = new Date();
    return startPlayingTime.getTime();
}

function getCurrentTime(){
    currentTime = new Date();
    return currentTime.getTime();
}

function getTime(){
    var a = getCurrentTime() - startPlayingTime;
    return a;
}

function getMoney(){
    var price = getTime()/3600000*tarifPerHour;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = price.toFixed(2);
    return price;
}

function stopTime(){
    if (timerId) {
        clearInterval(timerId);  // останавливаем таймер
        timerId = 0;
    }
    
    var price = getTime()/3600000*tarifPerHour;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = price.toFixed(2) + " рубля";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="resetStartTime()">Начать игру</button>
<button onclick="stopTime()">Закончить</button>
<button onclick="getMoney()">Сумма</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: `function resetStartTime() { clearInterval(timerId); ...`

Comment: @Igor, согласен, справедливо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Поставить setInterval():

```
var timer = setInterval(getMoney, 1000);
```

getMoney - без скобок, 1000 - это 1 секунда (1000 миллисекунд)

Comment: Стоп интервала - clearInterval(timer);